# Is there a way to automatically input the value “1” when the user decides to press 'enter' without giving a value?

Tags: python-3.x

How do I pre-set the system to give the display the value '1' if they do not enter any value (i.e., user just press enter). I kept having the error whereby the system forces me to have a number.[image]

```
   def get_variance():
        while True:
            variance = input("Please enter variance which must be greater than 0! ")
            try:
                value = int(variance)
                if value > 0:                       
                    print(f"Variance inserted is: {value}.")
                    break
                else:
                    print("You have entered a value less than 0, try again!")
            except ValueError:
                print("Amount must be a number, try again")
    get_variance()
```

Answer (score 1):

You first :

```
pip install pynput
```

Then you can use the following code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
def get_variance():
    while True:
        variance = input("Please enter variance which must be greater than 0! ")
        keyboard = Controller()
        keyss = "enter"

        if keyss =='enter':
            print('You must enter the number one')
        else:

            try:
                value = int(variance)
                if value > 0:
                    print(f"Variance inserted is: {value}.")
                    break

                else:
                    print("You have entered a value less than 0, try again!")
            except ValueError:
                print("Amount must be a number, try again")
get_variance()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Using the EAFP strategy of "easier to ask forgiveness than permission".

```py
while True:
    try:
        value = int(input("Enter something >>"))
        if value > 0:
            break
        else:
            continue
    except EOFError:
        value = 1
    except ValueError:
        continue
```